# Why live share not work on visual-studio code-oss?

Tags: node.js, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, icu

I have installed in my arch system code-oss following this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code i have also modified product.json ,installed code-features and code-marketplace but doesn't work, i read a lot of thread about this topic but i don't found any solution [Those are the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2NMm.png)

Comment: As the error complains about icu missing, try installing the icu package in arch linux.

Comment: now i tried to launch pacman -S icu  , but it says already installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the latest upgrade of the `icu` package to version 71.1 broke some dependency requirements for the live share extension.

There is already some discussion happening in the official Github live-share feedback repository, most notably [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/4646). As of now, no general fix is available, but what seems to work for now is to install the [old version 70](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icu70) of `icu` from the AUR.

Example if you have `trizen` installed:

```
trizen -S icu70
```

This might take a while because it has to be compiled. Alternatively, there is also a [binary build available for version 69](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icu69-bin):

```
trizen -S icu69-bin
```

Comment: Thank you, i solved my problem with your suggestion